# How to sum or/and difference time in Minutes : Seconds : Milliseconds format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, milliseconds

I need to calculate rally results table in PHP. So i have varchar string column in the mysql db in 'mm:ss:milliseconds' format ('03:54:78' for example).

How can i do the ($time1 + $time2)  and ($time1 - $time2) operations in PHP ?

Comment: First of all change you column type to `TIME`

Comment: it's a string. tear it apart into its constituent bits, and then it's just simple math.

Comment: You can use **explode()** function and convert it to miliseconds and make operations with them and finally convert it back. But better idea is, save it as number of miliseconds directly in database.

Comment: @juergen-d , I cant use TIME type because ti truncates value for seconds more than 60. Milliseconds can be up to 99.